# Правильно ли указана высота и ширина элементов в вёрстке?

Tags: css

```
Насколько корректно указана ширина и высота элементов?  
https://codepen.io/Krutov/pen/ZrdQeE
```

Comment: DOCTYPE :)    нужно его указать. meta description, а то поисковик не поймет вас

Comment: это не вопрос и его не сюда писать нужно

Comment: Про DOCTYPE я в курсе. просто codepen его не воспринимает, я и не указал.

Comment: footer можно вынести из main, класы название иметь связаное с контентом, а не text_style. но это все здесь не имеет смысла, все хорошо как на меня, но это не вопрос и здесь не нужно писать такое

Comment: Понял Вас! Благодарю за выявленные неточности, по поводу написания своей тематики именно здесь, на будущее учту!